# JavaFX: When the user presses the mouse within a panel, its color should be changed randomly?

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I am having trouble with my code. I had to make a chessboard for a previous problem. Now I have to use that same code to display 8X8 grids which are initially white. Once clicked on, they should, they should change color randomly. Can someone please help, here is a copy of my code.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class ChessBoardColor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        int size = 8 ;

        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {

            for (int color = 0; color < size; color ++) {


                StackPane panel = new StackPane();
                String boxcolor ;
                if ((row + color) % 2 == 0) {
                    boxcolor = "red";
                } else {
                    boxcolor = "black";
                }
                panel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FFFFFF;");
                pane.add(panel, color, row);



                pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                pane.setStroke();
                });
               }

            }
        }



        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            pane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
            pane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this code simply find the node where the user click and apply style like you know:

```
public class ChessBoardColor extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    int size = 8;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {

        for (int color = 0; color < size; color++) {

            StackPane panel = new StackPane();
            String boxcolor; //initial box color = "white" if you want it white initialy

            if ((row + color) % 2 == 0) {//I suppose it's your chessboard color
                boxcolor = "red";
            } else {
                boxcolor = "black";

            }
            panel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + boxcolor + ";");
            pane.add(panel, color, row);

            pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> { 

                Node target = (Node) e.getTarget(); // you find where the user click
                if (target instanceof StackPane) {

                    String radomColor = getRandomColor(); // choose a random color
                    ((StackPane) target).setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + radomColor + ";"); // apply it like you already know
                }

            });
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE,
                Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
        pane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(5, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
                Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
    }

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500, 500));
    primaryStage.show();

}

private String getRandomColor() { // simple random color generator

    String colors[] = new String[] {"blue", "yellow", "green", "purple"};
    Random ran = new Random();
    int randomColourIndex = ran.nextInt(4);     
    return colors[randomColourIndex];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```